# Given two B trees, T1 and T2, so that every element is T2 is bigger than every element in T1, joined into a B tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, b-tree

Given two B trees of same t, T1 and T2, so that every element is T2 is bigger than every element in T1.
I have to join them into a single B tree in the most efficient way.

Any ideas?

Comment: *"of same t"*: what does that mean? Same height? Same branching factor?

Comment: same branching factor

Comment: So height can be different?

Comment: yes it can also be different